# homomorphic filtering for image restoration of colored image

Tags: matlab

Can anyone please help me on applying homomorphic filter on a **colored image** in matlab?
I know homomorphic filtering for gray images, but it is getting hard for colored images.

```
I = imread('E:\degraded images\village.jpg');
imshow(I)

%I am using a colored image

I = im2double(I);
I = log(1 + I);
M = 2*size(I,1) + 1;
N = 2*size(I,2) + 1;
sigma = 10;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:N,1:M);
centerX = ceil(N/2);
centerY = ceil(M/2);
gaussianNumerator = (X - centerX).^2 + (Y - centerY).^2;
H = exp(-gaussianNumerator./(2*sigma.^2));
H = 1 - H;

imshow(H,'InitialMagnification',25)

H = fftshift(H);
If = fft2(I, M, N);
Iout = real(ifft2(repmat( H, [1, 1, 3 ] ) .* If));
Iout = Iout(1:size(I,1),1:size(I,2));

Ihmf = exp(Iout) - 1;
imshowpair(I, Ihmf, 'montage');
```

The last imshowpair is not working for double datatype. If I convert it into gray image, then there will be another problem of converting gray image into color image.

Comment: Did you try applying homomorphic filtering to each channel individually?  This code looks like it only works for grayscale images.  Consider putting this into a `for` loop and doing this for each channel in your image.

Comment: [imshowpair](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/images/ref/imshowpair.html) should work for [truecolor images](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html#f2-12468). Maybe you need to convert from doubles to the truecolor format. I don't have Matlab on this computer so I can't test it myself, but let me know if this helps.

Comment: how to convert image from double to truecolor

Comment: Okay, so doubles in the range [0.0, 1.0] are okay for truecolor, but if they are in the range [0.0 255.0], then they won't work with functions such as [image](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/image.html) (read the tips section). To scale to [0.0, 1.0], divide by 255.0 . However, that said, I think your problem is more likely solved by smn's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are processing the trucolor image as three independent channels but then selecting only the first (red) for the exponential and imshowpair.

Replace this line:

```
Iout = Iout(1:size(I,1),1:size(I,2));
```

with

```
Iout = Iout(1:size(I,1),1:size(I,2),:);
```

to keep all three color channels.

**Updated based on error message in comment:**

Based on the error message in the comments it appears `imshowpair` is not working as it is not available in your version of MATLAB (R2010a), it was added to the Image Processing Toolbox in R2012a. Use this line as suggested by @rayryeng instead:

```
imshow(cat(2,I,Ihmf));
```

Comment: still **imshowpair** is not working and giving error

    `??? Undefined function or method 'imshowpair' for input arguments of type 'double'.

    Error in ==> trialhomo at 39
    H= imshowpair(I, Ihmf, 'montage');`

>how to recify it

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using? `imshowpair` was added in to the Image Processing Toolbox in R2012a. It is more likely MATLAB cannot find the function `imshowpair` rather than being a problem with data type 'double'. Check if MATLAB can find the function by typing `which imshowpair`

Comment: The function `imshowpair` is not available in R2010a. `imshowpair(I, Ihmf, 'montage');` puts `I` and `Ihmf` next to each other on the same image. You can achieve a similar result by using subplots `subplot(121), imshow(I), subplot(122), imshow(Ihmf)`

Comment: @smn - Using `subplot` provides a small gap in between the images.  I would recommend doing this instead:  `imshow(cat(2,I,Ihmf));`.  This effectively performs what `imshowpair` does.

Comment: @rayryeng Agreed, that more accurately replicates the functionality of  `imshowpair(,,'montage')` and is also a more concise solution.